# Hola, error con un post de FirebaseDatabase en flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, realtime-database

Hola amigos tengo un error en mi codigo pero no encuentro la solucion ya intente casi de todo, llevo dos dias queriendo resolverlo

Le dejo mi codigo

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    DatabaseReference postsRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child("Posts");

    postsRef.once().then((DataSnapshot snap) {
          var keys = snap.value.keys;
          var Data = snap.value;

          postList.clear();

          for (var individualKey in keys) {
            Post posts = Post(
              Data[individualKey]["images"],
              Data[individualKey]["description"],
              Data[individualKey]["data"],
              Data[individualKey]["time"],
            );
            postList.add(posts);
          }
          setState(() {
            print("Lenght: $postList.lenght");
          });
        });
  }
```

### Y esto es lo que me arroja la terminal :

[image: Terminal]

Comment: Podrías mejorar el formato de tu pregunta, poner el código y los errores en un bloques respectivamente para que sea mas fácil para los demás ayudarte. Saludos

Comment: Listo, Nose como se puede agregar la terminal xd
Perdon <3

Comment: El código y los mensajes de error siempre _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Para agregar el texto que aparece en la terminal, simplemente selecciona tal texto, cópialo, y pégalo en la pregunta, dándole el formato correspondiente. Además, no olvides colocar tanto en el título como en el cuerpo de la pregunta el problema _específico_ que estás teniendo.